# Split full searchterm in single terms SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, post, search

I'm working on a small FAQ site with a Searchfunction

Right now i use SQL and search for the right entry like this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <label>
    Search
    <input type="text" name="keywords" autocomplete="off">
  </label>

  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
require_once '../db/connect.php';

if (isset($_GET['keywords'])&& empty($_GET['keywords']) === false) {
  // code...
   $keywords = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

   $query = $connection->query("
    SELECT question, answer
    FROM FAQ
    WHERE tags LIKE '%{$keywords}%'

   ");

   ?>
```

When i search for "WLAN" it shows the entry where i have "Wlan, Connection, ..." in the tags. 
When i search for Connection it shows the same entry. Great so far! 
But when i search for "Connection with WLAN" it doesn't work... obviously. 
Is there an easy method to implement this?

It would be something like '%{$keywords}%' where i can say it just has to be equal to some part of the string.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would have to loop and add multiple `LIKE` statements.

Comment: Don't rely on the `real_escape_string()` functions to prevent SQL injection, [they alone are not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: What database are you using? It may have full-text search capabilities built in.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for your concern, but this site won't be accessible from the www, it's just for employees, so security wont be that much of an issue. But i'll do it if i get around .

Comment: _"so security wont be that much of an issue"_ Don't ever think that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky true... i'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **in** clause instead of like

```
SELECT question, answer
FROM FAQ
WHERE tags in ($keywords)
```

You will have to make a list of keywords which is delimited with commas and each keyword enclosed in single quotes. So **split** your input on **space** and formulate the keywords string as described.